# How can we achieve custom validation in django class based views(create and update view)

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I want to use uniqueness validation in class-based views.

Here I have createView where I want to add part_no uniqueness validation at the time of form post.

How can we achieve this?

Any solutions.

Views.py

```
class SparePartsCreate(CreateView): 
    template = 'maint/spareparts_form.html'
    model = SpareParts
    fields = ['name', 'description', 'part_no']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('spare_parts')

    form.py
    class SparePartForm(forms.ModelForm):
        name = forms.CharField(required=True, label='Spare Part Name')
        description = forms.CharField(required=True, label='Spare Part Description')
        part_no = forms.CharField(required=True, label='Spare Part Number', max_length=6)
        class Meta:
            model = SpareParts
            fields = ['name','description','part_no']
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
            super(SparePartForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

As we implement validation in function-based views in form.py under clean method.

For class-based views anything is there?

Answer (score 0):

```
class SparePartForm(forms.ModelForm):
        name = forms.CharField(required=True, label='Spare Part Name')
        description = forms.CharField(required=True, label='Spare Part Description')
        part_no = forms.CharField(required=True, label='Spare Part Number', max_length=6)
        class Meta:
            model = SpareParts
            fields = ['name','description','part_no']
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
            super(SparePartForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

       def clean_part_no(self, value):
          """ here you can validate the data  """
          if True:
             return value
          else:
             raise forms.validationError("error message ")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But here I have used class based view not fun based.

Comment: it's really doesn't matter, form doesn't depend upon the view you are using class base or function base

Comment: The CreateView rendering self create view form.

Answer (score 0):

```
def clean_part_no(self):
    part_no = self.cleaned_data.get('part_no')
    qs = SpareParts.objects.filter(part_no=part_no)
    if qs.exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError('This part_no already taken, please use a different one.')
    return part_no
```

either use this way in your forms.py or make it as `unique=True` in models.py file

Comment: Here I am using CreateView, so I think this clean method is not applicable.

Comment: If I use function-based views then clean method will work.

Comment: this you have to add in your forms, it should work for cbv also

Comment: Actually I am not getting part_no vale in form.py file.

Comment: This CreateView rendering self form. I have deleted the form in form.py. But my project is working same as previous i.e its not using the form.